# Is it appropriate to access window instead of $(window) when jQuery is used?

Tags: jquery

In a jQuery based code I have several places where the `window` object is accessed directly. Is this an acceptable practice or are there any drawbacks of such approach?

I thought `$(window)` is 1:1 replacement for `window`, but it is not. For example `"onhashchange" in window` works, but `"onhashchange" in $(window)` does not.

Other constructs where I access `window` are: `window.location`, `window.open`, `window.setTimeout`. Would it be better to find and use jQuery based replacements for all of them?

Comment: PS: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with accessing the window-object directly. jQuery should be used as a tool that helps you in client-side development. If the correct API is available natively, then by all means do use it. In most cases, the native API's are faster (although usually the differences are negligible).

If you really want to promoto consistency you could do the following to get access to the underlying window object:

```
$(window)[0].onhashchange = ...
```

But in my opinion it's just easier to access window directly.

Comment: and if there's a cross browser issue it will be there in both cases

Comment: Well, for cross browser issues, you'd be better of using jQuery which abstracts those things away for you

Comment: that's my point exactly. Your example will suffer the same cross browser issues (if there were any) than not using jquery. So there's no gain from wrapping and then unwrapping the element

Comment: Yes, exactly, the wrapper is just taking the long route. I wouldn't ever use it. But if you wish to do anything through jQuery it could be a practice. I wouldn't recommend it though

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should not feel forced by your library to use every bit of it. Where it would "feel wrong" to rely on jQuery is for example with URL forwarding (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638449/623400):

```
$(location).attr("href", "http://www.google.de");
```

A place where I would trust in jQuery only is the selector API. I've seen lots of code mixing several approaches (querySelectorAll, getElementById ...). Here, consistency is key!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with it.  From my point of view `window` is a global variable and should be used like one.

Libraries are great until you want to swap one out.  Your client code will be easier to migrate/refactor to another library if you try and stick with the core.

I think of jQuery as a helper to hide the complexities of dom manipulation and http requests - that, I believe, it's top notch for.